# Adhoc distribution via Xcode beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a question regarding swift release, I want to rewrite some part of my app, so can I distribute app via ad hoc compiled for ios 7 in Xcode 6?

Or it's a bad idea to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple have promised binary compatibility going forward, with source code changes to be expected. Therefore I don't see an issue even if you are distributing frameworks in an ad hoc manner.